# What is the idiomatic way to get `auto` to perform case analysis?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

```
Inductive Foo : nat -> Type :=
  | a : Foo 1.

(* ... *)

Goal forall m, Foo m -> m = 1.
Proof.
  auto.
Fail Qed.
```

Is there a straightforward approach to do this?

Comment: `auto` is not really geared towards this, unless you want to provide a theory for `Foo` that can solve goals in a "logic programming sytle". I'd suggest defining you own tactic to destruct terms.

Comment: A. Chlipala's `crush` tactic can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Hint Extern` together with a tactic script that executes the case analysis.  For example, this one will use `destruct` if the argument is a variable, and use `inversion_clear` otherwise:

```
Inductive Foo : nat -> Type :=
| a : Foo 1.

Hint Extern 1 => match goal with
                 | [ H : Foo ?m |- _ ]
                   => first [ is_var m; destruct H | inversion_clear H ]
                 end.

Goal forall m, Foo m -> m = 1.
Proof.
  auto.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Via *Programming Language Foundations*, chapter [Theory and Practice of Automation in Coq Proofs](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/UseAuto.html):

> Note that proof search tactics never perform any rewriting step (tactics `rewrite`, `subst`), nor any case analysis on an arbitrary data structure or property (tactics `destruct` and `inversion`), nor any proof by induction (tactic `induction`). So, proof search is really intended to automate the final steps from the various branches of a proof. It is not able to discover the overall structure of a proof.

So there is really no way to do this; this goal should be solved manually, and then added to the hint database (`Hint blah.`).